# ¿Cómo agrupar las variables de un fichero excel en R por días?

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un estudio de las cajas, volumen, vehículos ,etc de una empresa de reparto.
Necesito obtener gráficas y métricas por días de la semana, es decir, por ejemplo, volumen por días, para calcular media y desviación típica (Por ejemplo, necesito saber una media de cuántos vehículos por día se emplean, cuánto volumen por día..)
De momento, he hecho gráficas enfrentando cada variable con los días:

```
plot(x = datos$Dias, main = "Volumen por días",
     y=datos$Volumen, xlab = "Días ",
     ylab = "Volumen")
```

Pero obtengo una gráfica bastante fea, pues me aparecen domingo y sabado (para los cuales no tengo ningun dato).

Comment: Añada por favor la estructura de tus datos, -> `str(datos)`, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias mostrar la estructura de tus datos en tus preguntas, seria mas facil de entender y te ayudaria a ti a conseguir mejores respuestas.
Capaz lo siguiente pueda ayudarte

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library("dplyr")

datos %>%
    filter(!Dias %in% c("domingo", "sabado")) %>%
    group_by(Dias) %>%
    summarize(avg_vol_por_dia = mean(Volumen))
```

De esa forma conseguiras un nuevo dataframe (un tibble en realidad) con dos columnas y cinco filas:

```
       Dias avg_vol_por_dia
1     lunes         123
2    martes         345
3 miercoles       25436
4    jueves        1234
5   viernes        1344
```

*Obs: Los valores de avg_vol_por_dia los puse de forma aleatoria con proposito de mostrar como quedaria el dataframe.*

Notese que con la linea `filter(!Dias %in% c("domingo", "sabado"))` se han filtrado todas las observaciones que contienen sabado y domingo, es por eso que en la nueva tabla no se encuentran esos dias.

Podrias reemplazar `filter(!Dias %in% c("domingo", "sabado"))` por `filter(Dias == "lunes")` y obtendras la sigte. tabla, solamente con observaciones del dia lunes :

```
       Dias vol_por_dia
1     lunes         123
```

Con la linea `summarize(avg_vol_por_dia = mean(Volumen))` se ha calculado el promedio de los volumenes para cada dia, pero en vez de usar la funcion **mean** podrias usar  otra que te brinde los resultados que buscas, por ejemplo `summarize(sd_vol_por_dia = sd(Volumen))` con lo que calcularias la desviacion estandar del volumen por cada dia.

Ten en cuenta que si quieres guardar las nuevas tablas que generes debes asignarlas a un objeto nuevo.

Podrias realizar tus graficos a partir de la nueva tabla, ya no tendrias sabado ni domingo en tu eje de abcisas, y podrias usar la variable **vol_por_dia** en tu eje de ordenadas.
Te dare un ejemplo con la libreria **ggplot2**

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library("ggplot2")
nuevos_datos <- datos %>%
                   filter(!Dias %in% c("domingo", "sabado")) %>%
                   group_by(Dias) %>%
                   summarize(avg_vol_por_dia = mean(Volumen))

ggplot(nuevos_datos, aes(x = Dias, y = avg_vol_por_dia, color = Dias)) +
  geom_col()
```

Con lo que obtienes [image: grafico barras]

Creo que estos enlances te seran de gran ayuda:

[Selecting columns and renaming are so easy with dplyr](https://blog.exploratory.io/selecting-columns-809bdd1ef615#.tyeuriw0w)

[Filtering Data with dplyr](https://blog.exploratory.io/filter-data-with-dplyr-76cf5f1a258e)